# Check urls (strings)

Tags: python-3.x, url

I have some troubles in parsing urls as strings. i need to check if urls belongs to domains in whitelist, but the check is miserably failing. I woulf like to understand the reason and if my code is lacking.

```
whitelist = []
whitelist_file = open(whitelist_file, 'r')
url = whitelist_file.readline()
for url in whitelist_file:
    whitelist = whitelist + [str(url)]
whitelist_file.close()

test_file = open(test_file, 'r')
url_to_check = test_file.readlines()

for url in url_to_check:
    for word in whitelist:
        print(str(word), str(url), word in url)
        print("-----")
```

this is the printout of what above (so you have samples of the checked strings). You can see the it fails for a2a.eu

```
a2a.eu
 https://www.medgadget.com/2017/10/adenosine-a2a-receptor-antagonist-pipeline-insights-2017.html
 False
-----
ansa.it
 https://www.medgadget.com/2017/10/adenosine-a2a-receptor-antagonist-pipeline-insights-2017.html
 False
-----
atlantia.it
 https://www.medgadget.com/2017/10/adenosine-a2a-receptor-antagonist-pipeline-insights-2017.html
 False
-----
azimut-group.com
 https://www.medgadget.com/2017/10/adenosine-a2a-receptor-antagonist-pipeline-insights-2017.html
 False
-----
a2a.eu
 https://www.a2a.eu/en/2017-financial-calendar-a2a-spa
 False
-----
ansa.it
 https://www.a2a.eu/en/2017-financial-calendar-a2a-spa
 False
-----
atlantia.it
 https://www.a2a.eu/en/2017-financial-calendar-a2a-spa
 False
-----
azimut-group.com
 https://www.a2a.eu/en/2017-financial-calendar-a2a-spa
 False
-----
a2a.eu
 http://www.a2a.eu/en
 False
-----
ansa.it
 http://www.a2a.eu/en
 False
-----
atlantia.it
 http://www.a2a.eu/en
 False
-----
azimut-group.com
 http://www.a2a.eu/en
 False
```

thanks

Comment: The code you've displayed doesn't seem to produce the output you have in your question.

Comment: You should be using the  urllib.parse module to get the domains out of the urls. Then you can check each domain against your list of 'whites'.

Comment: the check is sustantially this one: print(..., word in url)

Comment: @Bill Bell: thanks, but actually I'd prefer to keep track on my disk of all positive and negative checks and store the whitelisted and blacklisted ones on local files. I think that the urllib.parse module doesn't allow me to do that

Comment: OK. By using `word in url` you are asking whether the `word` appears *anywhere* in `url`. A more careful check would involve comparing just a domain name with the domain name taken from a url.

Comment: Line 3 is not correct. It is only reading one line in the whitelist file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL in line 5 contains the newline character. Call strip() and that should fix it:

```
whitelist = []
whitelist_file = open(whitelist_file, 'r')
url = whitelist_file.readline()
for url in whitelist_file:
  whitelist = whitelist + [str(url.strip())]
  whitelist_file.close()

test_file = open(test_file, 'r')
url_to_check = test_file.readlines()

for url in url_to_check:
  for word in whitelist:
    print(str(word), str(url), word in url)
    print("-----")
```

Comment: Excellent. This is the solution. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, according to your output for some of the cases this check should produce a True result. That is really just judging by the output print. My suspicion is that your url or word (in whilelist) are not the string objects that you think they are; try to convert to str in your print statement as

```
  print(str(word), str(url), str(word) in str(url))
```

additionally you seem to just to check for the domain, have a look at urllib https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html, where you can dissect the url into the domain part only and check against it:

```
  from urllib.parse import urlparse
  print(str(word), str(url), str(word) in urlparse(str(url)).hostname
```

Comment: @ Marcel Zoll - thank you. i've tried both suggestions but still unsuccesfully. It appears it is something different. It might it be something with the encoding ? I mean Utf8, Ansi, ... ??